# HOW TO CASE OVER A SET OF ELEMENTS IN SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, case

let's say that I have a column1 which was formed by many objects (in a json array). I need to something like they do here: https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-pivot-table/
So I need to case over a set of elements type of event can be: ('Urban', 'Urban', 'Rural')... then when I case for 'Urban' it gives the next error:

> ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must not return a set.

In the end I need to count the number of events happening, but sometimes I have 2 events per set, so it cannot give a boolean... should I subquery in any way? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
select * from 
    (select jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'roadEnv' as road_env,
           SUM(CASE WHEN (jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type') = 'Urban' THEN event_counts ELSE NULL END) AS U,
           --SUM(CASE WHEN jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type' = 'Urban' THEN event_counts ELSE NULL END) AS R,
           --SUM(CASE WHEN jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type' = 'Urban' THEN event_counts ELSE NULL END) AS M,
           COUNT(1)::real as event_counts
    from
      (SELECT  (s.fields->'externalEvents') as event_all
       FROM    addon_session s
       WHERE <filter> and jsonb_typeof(s.fields->'externalEvents')='array') as data 
GROUP BY 1, 2 ) as data 
where road_env is not null and "Events" <> 'AAA'

--- WE NEED TO COUNT OR SUM THEM I GUESS... HOW? COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Urban' THEN 'URBAN' END as 'u')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think replacing

```
(jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type') = 'Urban'
```

with

```
'Urban' = ANY (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type')
```

is what you want. (That is, if at least one `Type` has to be `'Urban'` but not all. Or

```
'Urban' = ALL (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(event_all)->>'Type')
```

if all `Type`s have to be `'Urban'`)